# Two difference implementations of IRSensor code?

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I was working with IRSensor and  i found out that there are two different implementations of the IRSensors. The IRSensor available in diamondback, most of the part is commented out while the one available on-line in the site https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/browser/server/sensors/ir/IRSensor.cc?rev=a9373a6e19be81f4efe2729c71ec7964d5c1131d have no line commented out. I didn't understand the problem why the lines are commented out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10788/two-difference-implementations-of-irsensor-code??/) by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2011-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The difference between the IR Sensor present in Diamondback is the new version of IRSensor specified in the site.

---

Originally posted by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) with karma: 94 on 2011-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0